# Given Cartan matrix, find root and Dynkin diagram

Tags: lie-groups, root-systems, dynkin-diagrams

Given:

Cartan matrix of $\tilde{\mathfrak{so}}=B_2=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -2 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$

The formula for the components of a Cartan matrix $\textbf{A}$ is $A_{ij}=2\frac{\alpha_i\cdot\alpha_j}{\alpha_i\cdot\alpha_i}$.

I have determined that the length of $\alpha_j$ is (thanks @TravisWillse) $\sqrt2$ that of $\alpha_i$, and the angle between $\alpha_i$ and $\alpha_j$ is 135 degrees.

If a reader struggling would like to know whow I got this let me know and I will Tex it up in the future, but for now, I am the student.

What is my next step in drawing the Dynkin diagram?

What is my next step in drawing the root diagram?

For the root diagram, I've been given the suggestion to use Weyl reflections.

Can anyone provide me some instruction in the next steps I take on the journey from Cartan matrix to Dynkin diagram and root diagram?

Comment: The *square* of the length of the long root ($\alpha_1$ using the Bourbaki convention) is twice that of the short root; the length itself is $\sqrt 2$ times that of the short root.

Comment: To draw the Dynkin diagram, since you know that it has two roots (the Cartan matrix is $2 \times 2$) all that remains is to figure out the degree of the edge, which in turn is determined by the square of ratio of the length of the long root to that of the short root.

Comment: @TravisWillse That's so funny, I just corrected the same thing in my notes before checking this before bed. Indeed, dividing the equation for $A_{12}$ by the equation for the  $A_{21}$ yields $|\alpha_j|^2=2|\alpha_i|^2$, where I mistook $|\alpha_j|^2# for the norm.

Comment: @TravisWillse Now regarding that bit about the # of lines. Can you expound on why the # of lines is the square of the length ratio? Does the 135 degrees not play into the Dynkin diagram?

Comment: @TravisWillse Also, how does the reader know which open dot in my Dynkin diagram is $\alpha_j$ and which is $\alpha_i$? It can't be that I can just draw my arrow in either direction and call the dots whatever I want, can it?

Comment: It does, in the sense that the possible angle between the simple roots are in bijection with the possible valences: single, $2 \pi / 3$; double, $3 \pi / 4$; triple, $5 \pi / 6$.

Comment: By convention the arrow always points toward the short root, but notice that for $B_2$ the two possible arrow directions give the same diagram (at least, if you don't label the roots).

Comment: That latter fact reflects the isomorphism $B_2 \cong C_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've actually collected all of the information you need from the Cartan matrix in order to construct the Dynkin and root diagrams: The quantities $\langle \alpha_i, \alpha_j \rangle$, $$1 \leq i \leq j .$$

1. You know that that the Dynkin diagram has two nodes (the Cartan matrix is $2 \times 2$), all that remains is to find the valence of the edge connecting them, which you can read off the computation $||\alpha_1||^2 = 2 ||\alpha_2||^2$. The arrow, by convention, points from the long root to the short root.
2. If you apply Weyl reflections to the simple roots (until applying further reflections generates no new roots) generates the root diagram.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help throughout this problem! The algorithmic approach from Cartan matrix -> root and Dynkin diagram is so much more clear now! Regarding the # of lines, can you explain why the 2 in the equation you mention corresponds to the # of lines. I'm having trouble finding that convention in textbooks (all I know is the angle-> # of lines convention), even though it appears totally legitimate. Responded to the comment above, I want to bring up something regarding $B_2$ versus $C_2$. I will do some below.

Comment: Cartan matrix for $B_2=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -2 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, Cartan matrix for $C_2=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 \\ -2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$. Common in textbooks, the Dynkin diagram for $B_2$ is draw with the arrow pointing to the right, and the Dynkin diagram for $C_2$ is draw with the arrow pointing to the left. So what is the convention?

Comment: Yes, that's the usual way of drawing the diagrams. In particular, with both of those conventions, usually the left root is denoted $\alpha_1$ and the right is denoted $\alpha_2$, so the enumeration of roots depends on whether we view the diagram as for the $B_2$ root system or the $C_2$ one. But the information encoded by the Dynkin diagram (in particular, not including root labels) doesn't depend on the orientation of the diagram, i.e., $B_2$ and $C_2$ have the diagram, reflecting the fact that their root systems are isomorphic.

Comment: At the level of (complex) Lie algebras, this identification encodes the isomorphism $\mathfrak{so}(5, \Bbb C) \cong \mathfrak{sp}(4, \Bbb C)$. At the level of real Lie algebras, this encodes three different isomorphisms of real Lie algebras; they can be read off this answer on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/a/81382/26266

Comment: Thank you so much for your diligence in this answer! :)

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you found it helpful.

Comment: By the way, I find a good mnemonic for the convention of "where the arrow points" is to see the tip of the arrow as a "less than" or "greater than" sign. Then e.g. if you write $\alpha_1 --> \alpha_2$ it means $\alpha_2$ is the shorter root.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg That's a great mnemonic---I'd always just memorized "from the long root to the short root", but of course that's arbitrary.

Comment: @TravisWillse 15+ now ;)